# Как с помощью регулярного выражения найти первый операнд со знаком

Tags: javascript, html, css, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать так, что бы в калькуляторе после ввода первого операнда и знака операции вводился другой операнд вместо них, как это реализовать? Как я понял нужно создать одну временную переменную где сохранять первый операнд со знаком а потом уже добавлять строку к второму. Как я понимаю нужно найти с помощью регулярного выражение первый операнд включая знак, как сделать это? Набросок :

```
function rememberFirstOperand(value)
{   
    var rep1 =/[*|/|-|+]/;
    var rep2 = /[0-9](?=[*|/|+|-])/;
    var tempValue = 0;

    if (rep1.test(calculator.answer.value) && rep2.test(calculator.answer.value))//   / * - +
    {
        tempValue=calculator.answer.value;
    }

    calculator.answer.value+=temp;
```

Comment: А  если чуть оторваться от программирования, то задача какая? Просто может статься что вас изначальный калькулятор стоит реализовать классическим способом, через стек операндов и стек операций. Тогда ваша проблема вероятно отпадет, но во многих частных случаях это оверкилл

Comment: Задача была сделать калькулятор именно етим способом но нужно щас переделать что бы первое числа запоминалось и строка ввода перезаписалась вторым операндом

Comment: именно этим - это каким? Если у вас калькулятор по уму сделан, то никаких извратов с поиском регуляркой не надо, вот что я хочу сказать